# Package meta miscalculating confidence intervals for individual studies with command metamean

Tags: r

I am running a random-effects meta-analysis of mean differences using meta package, command metamean. My dataset includes (among other variables):

npatients (numeric): number of patients within the study
dif (numeric): mean difference
sddif (numeric) standard deviation of dif

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
library(meta) 
data < data.frame("npatients"=c(43,11,37,15,14),"dif"=c(0,.11,-.02,-.19,.04),"sddif"=c(.54,.21,.30,.38,.67))
metadif <- metamean(n=npatients,mean=dif,sd=sddif,method.tau="REML",comb.fixed=FALSE, data=data) 
metadif
```

However the confidence intervals calculated for the individual studies do not make much sense and do not match calculation by hand (mean +/- 1.96 SD). Examples:

Study 1:
dif = 0 /
sd = .54 /
95% CI (calculated by meta): -.16 to .16

Study 2:
dif = .11 /
sd = .21 /
95% CI (calculated by meta): -.01 to .23

Study 3:
dif = -.02 /
sd = .30 /
95% CI (calculated by meta): -.12 to .08

Oddly, I took a look at the object metadif generated by meta and the Standard error seems to be correctly calculated internally.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: library(meta) 
data <- data.frame("npatients"=c(43,11,37,15,14),"dif"=c(0,.11,-.02,-.19,.04),"sddif"=c(.54,.21,.30,.38,.67)) <br>
metadif <- metamean(n=npatients,mean=dif,sd=sddif, method.tau="REML",comb.fixed=FALSE, data=data) . 
metadif

Comment: Thank you, Cristoph. I have now added a reproducible example to my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation to calculate the confidence interval for an individual study is wrong.

Instead of mean +/- 1.96 SD, the correct formula is mean +/- 1.96 SE, i.e., you have to use the standard error of the mean which can be calculated as SE = sqrt(SD^2 / n).

The confidence interval for the first study, for example, can thus be calculated with the following R command:

```
0 + c(-1, 1) * 1.96 * sqrt(0.54^2 / 43)
```

This corresponds to the results provided by R function metamean().

Best wishes, Guido